# Как осуществить подмену текста из html-файла в PHP?

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения, str-replace

**Вводные**: есть php скрипт выполняющий подгрузку html-файла из подпапки, есть задача после подгрузки подменить текст *(например {getDomain})* на вывод переменной *(например getDomain($domain))*.
Выполнить echo прямо в этих html-файлах не выходит, поскольку они подгружаются из директории *(которая изменяется в зависимости от домена запрашиваемого сайта)*.

**Пробовал**: preg_replace(file_get_contents(...)) и str_replace(file_get_contents(...)) - замена просто не происходит (дело в фигурных скобках?).

**Код**:

```
<?php 
//Обработчик функций

//Объявляем переменные нужные для всех сайтов
$path = $_GET["path"];
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
// Подставить ключи счётчиков Roistat необходимо здесь:
$RoistatKeys = array(
    '...' => '05b3c6c5bc4929f3fc4573d83424469c',
);
function getSiteDirectory($domain = '') {
    $return = dirname(__FILE__).'/sites/'.$domain;
    return $return;
}

function getRoistatCode($domain = '') {
    $key = $RoistatKeys[$domain];
    $part1 = "<script>(function(w, d, s, h, id) {w.roistatProjectId = id; w.roistatHost = h;var p = d.location.protocol == ".'https:" ? "https://" : "http://"'.';var u = /^.*roistat_visit=[^;]+(.*)?$/.test(d.cookie) ? "/dist/module.js" : "/api/site/1.0/"+id+"/init?referrer="+encodeURIComponent(d.location.href);var js = d.createElement(s); js.charset="UTF-8"; js.async = 1; js.src = p+h+u; var js2 = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; js2.parentNode.insertBefore(js, js2);})(window, document,'."'script', 'cloud.roistat.com',";
    $part2 = ');</script>';
    $return = $part1."'".$key."'".$part2;
    return $return;
}
function getAllCode($domain = '') {
    $return = getRoistatCode($domain).''.$anyCodeUWantToBeOnEveryPage;
    return $return;
}

function doReplace($content = '', $domain = '')
{
    $replacedHtml = preg_replace('{getAllCode}', getAllCode($domain), $content);
    $replacedFinally = preg_replace('{getDomain}', $domain, $replacedHtml);
    return $replacedFinally;
}

$sitedir = dirname(__FILE__).'/sites/'.$domain.'/';
if ($path == null) {
    $result = readfile($sitedir.'index.html');
} else {
    $result = readfile($sitedir.$path.'.html');
}
echo doReplace($result, $domain);

?>
```

**.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)(/?)$ ?path=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Как было сказано выше, при таком коде, замена просто не происходит. Товарищи, куда копать?
Буду благодарен за конструктивную критику и указания в каких местах я проявил невнимательность!

Comment: не особо ясно зачем городить эти костыли с выводом html и заменой, если можно было вместо него сделать php файл который все сделает сам.

Comment: по сабжу, помимо комментария по поводу readfile, который необходимо замениьт на file_get_contents, еще следует читать до посинения раздел документации https://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: 1875 html-файлов. По срокам 2 дня осталось, определённо есть смысл возиться с костылями, спасибо за комментарий. Хотелось бы пояснений по поводу того, какой файл будет делать всё сам.

Comment: так контент файлов то одинаковый, помимо указанных кодов заменяемых,  или разный?

Comment: Разный, естественно, иначе бы спарсил все тексты, и запихнул в базу данных. Увы, так не получится - вот и горожу огород палками с мусором.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка состоит в применении функции `readfile()`, как для `str_replace()`, так и для `preg_replace()` необходимо преобразовать файл в строку. Для этого больше подходит `file_get_contents()`.